# Delete an object pointed by a pointer returned from another function

Tags: c++

An example,

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
vector<int>* F()
{
    vector<int>*x=new vector<int>(3);
    x[1]=1; x[2]=2; x[3]=3;
    return x;
}
```

Now I want to delete the vector or release that block of memory pointed by x in another function F1, something like:

```
bool F1(vector<int>*x)
{
    delete x; 
    return 1;
}
```

Is there anyway to achieve what I want?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes. That code. It's not a great idea though.

Comment: There's no reason to do this. Returning a concrete `vector` in post C++11 compiler is a must, since a `vector` is moveable. You don't need to return a newly allocated `vector`.

Comment: @40two Even in C++03. You're more likely to get copy elision than a move.

Comment: Actually I tried that and it didn't work, and all I got is that the pointer becomes NULL, but the memory wasn't released at all. I found it says the delete operator can only be effective when the new operator showed up before it in the same scope @OliCharlesworth Charlesworth

Comment: @juanchopanza thanks for the nice addition, I totally agree.

Comment: @user2961927 No way. Post some code that reproduces the behaviour you describe.

Comment: @user2961927 most probably you heard about problems with allocating object in a DLL and releasing on main program and vise versa and misunderstood, there is definitely no requirement to have delete in the same scope as operator new

Answer (score 2):

Make your `F()` function like

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
vector<int> F() {
    vector<int> x;
    x.resize(4);
    x[1]=1; x[2]=2; x[3]=3;
    return x;
}
```

No need for `F1()`.

Comment: yes seen it after made a comment, most probably he made a mistake rather than expecting using 4 elements lol